# Storybook Not Importing Custom Library Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, storybook

We have a component library that is bundled with Webpack 5. Here's a snippet of the Webpack config:

```js
module.exports = [
  {
    name: 'js',
    mode: 'production',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
      filename: 'index.js',
      libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
    },
    target: 'node',
    externals: {
      react: 'react',
    }
  }
];
```

and its `index.js` entrypoint:

```js
import Component1 from 'path/to/Component1';
import Component2 from 'path/to/Component2';
// ...

export default {
  Component1,
  Component2,
  // ...
};
```

We would like to use the components from this project in a consuming CRA 4 project. In that project, we are using Storybook to build out and test the UI.

We can use the components fine in the application proper (e.g., when run with `npm start`). It's when we try using the exports in Storybook that we run into problems. We are using Storybook 6.5.10.

For example, we have the following story file:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Component1 } from 'component-library'; // The component library in question

import StoryComponent from './StoryComponent'; // Component created in consuming project

export default {
  title: 'Story',
  component: StoryComponent,
  decorators: [
    (Story) => {
      return (
        <Component1>
          <Story />
        </Component1>
      );
    },
  ],
};

const Template = (args) => <StoryComponent {...args} />

export const Demo = Template.bind({});
```

When I open this story, I am getting an error: `el.type is undefined`. When I do `console.log({ Component1 })` in the decorator, it gets logged as `{ Component1: undefined }`.

From there, I tried importing the `component-library` top level export: `import cl from 'component-library'`. Sure enough, when I do `console.log({ cl })`, I get `{ cl: {} }`.

I suspect this is some Webpack configuration incompatibility. Is there something I need to do to the Storybook Webpack or the library's Webpack config to get this to import correctly? I've tried adding an alias to point `component-library` at `path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules/component-library')`, but that didn't help.